# Check that if-statement was true several times in a row

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a loop

```
count = 0;
do
{
    ...
    if (statement)
        count++;
    ...
} while (count != 3);
```

How to check that if statement was true three times at a stretch?

Comment: What do you mean `at a stretch`? If it's *not* true at least 3 times, your loop will never break anyway.

Comment: One by one, for example, on iteration №1,2,3, not like on iteration №2,5,8.

Comment: I believe  *at a stretch* means *in a row*

Comment: then you need another variable lets say `loop_counter` and then compare `count` and `loopcounter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the simplest thing to do is add an `else` to your `if`:

```
count = 0;
do
{
    ...
    if (statement)
        count++;
    else
        count = 0;
    ...
} while (count != 3);
```

However, you are risking an infinite loop since if there are no 3 consecutive true statements your count will never be 3.

Comment: Well, I believe that it had to be said, since there is a risk of an infinite loop that the OP might not be aware of here.

Answer (score 3):

You can reset count, if statement is false.

```
if (statement)
    count++;
else
    count = 0;
```

Also, note as mentioned in comments if 3 numbers doesn't come in a row, loop will never exit. Put a separate variable outside the `if` block that counts total iterations and use it in `while` condition too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the need for an additional counter, here. You said you want to *check* (not enforce) that the statement was true 3 times in a row.

```
count = 0;
var statementAlwaysTrue = true;

do
{
    ...
    if (statement)
        count++;
    else
        statementAlwaysTrue = false;
    ...
} while (count != 3);
```

After the loop has finished, you can evaluate `statementAlwaysTrue`. I'd obviously consider renaming this based on whatever `statement` is.

Comment: you need to check `statementAlwaysTrue` value in `while` condition?

Comment: @abdul Why? The OP said she wants to check that it "was". Not that it "is". Which would imply that this evaluation happen after it's finished.